# Cannot get file extension while sharing the file from Google Drive to my android application

Tags: android, google-drive-api, mime-types

**My Manifest file looks like below:**

```
<activity android:name=".home.HomeActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

**and i'm receiving like below in my activity:**

action: android.intent.action.SEND

mime-type:   image/*

uri:content: //media/external/images/media/218   // 218 is the filename(And i want the extension too.. )

**how to get the file extension when receiving the file from google drive? Is there any way to get it? Now i'm able to get only the mime type of the file. Can anyone please suggest me an idea?**